# How to change the date system in excel with code

Tags: python, excel, win32com, vba

I've got two excel spreadsheets I need to collate.  One uses the 1900 base year system, the other uses 1904.  I am filling the 1904 spreadsheet with data and then pulling in the 1900 sheet.  I'd like to change the date system to be based on 1900 for the first sheet I fill up so that when I pull in the other sheet it doesn't screw up the dates.

I can't find the magic words to change this setting in excel programatically. I'll take it in any language, with any module (but I'm using win32com and python).  I can figure it out from there.

Is it even possible?

Here are the instructions to do it manually:

http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2007-excel/why-does-excel-2007-change-dates-when-i-copy-and/b0544a7f-bd82-4b5a-a843-e6ae22f2ef63

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may not have been aware that you can record a macro while you make changes in *Excel Options*. This is what I get.

```
Sub Macro1()
    ActiveWorkbook.Date1904 = True
End Sub
```

Sometimes it is just easier to get the syntax and correct command through recording if it doesn't come off the top of your head.

Comment: I did not know you could do that.  Thanks for the info